# python eval list get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, list, eval

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 15 2016, 22:37:39) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> shlst="_t=[['00','bank','yx'],['04','airport','jc']]"
>>> eval(shlst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    _t=[['00','bank','yx'],['04','airport','jc']]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) evaluates a Python expression.  Assigning a value to a variable is not an expression.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you looking for `exec`?

Comment: thanks, that should be the cause

Comment: then what's the correct method to assign the list as-is, not split into character by character

Comment: do you require the variable `shlst`? `exec("_t=[['00','bank','yx'],['04','airport','jc']]")` would give you access to `_t`

Comment: that's it, great ,much thanks